# Linear Algebra Axler, 3e, Exercise 1c, P11

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

P11.  Prove that the intersection of every collection of subspaces of V is a subspace of V.

My solution was very similar to the one from [linearalgebras.com](http://linearalgebras.com/1c.html) --
Solution: Assume $U_i$ are subspaces of $V$, where $i\in I$. Now we will show $\cap_{i\in I}U_i$ is a subspace of $V$
Additive identity: by definition $0\in U_i$ for every $i\in I$, hence $0\in \cap_{i\in I}U_i$.

Closed under addition: if $x\in \cap_{i\in I}U_i$ and $y\in \cap_{i\in I}U_i$, then for any given $i\in I$, we have $x\in U_i$ and $y\in U_i$, hence $x+y\in U_i$ for $U_i$ is closed under addition. Therefore $x+y\in \cap_{i\in I}U_i$.

Closed under scalar multiplication: if $x\in \cap_{i\in I}U_i$, then $x\in U_i$ for any given $i\in I$. Then for any $\lambda\in\mathbb F$, we have $\lambda x\in U_i$ since $U_i$ is closed under scalar multiplication. Therefore $\lambda x\in \cap_{i\in I}U_i$.

However, I find it troubling to consider $U_i$ for $i\in \mathbb Z$ since the number of subsets could be uncountably infinite. Am I missing something? Are their alternate solutions?

Comment: Your solution is great. You are absolutely right to use an arbitrary index set.

Comment: @ervx Never having used it before, I find it a bit awkward. Isn't using an arbitrary index set equivalent to defining a function with an arbitrary/unspecified domain? How does that work?